# Show an alertDialog from another Activity Android

Tags: java, android

On my MainActivity I start a service of localization that runs across all of the otheractivities, when an event occurs I need to show an AlertDialog on the current activity but I can't get it working. this is the code for the alertDialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mMainActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage("test")
                           .setCancelable(false)
                           .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                   Intent intent = new Intent(mMainActivity.this,LocationDetails.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("placeId",1);
                                    startActivity(intent);

                               }
                           })
                           .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                    dialog.cancel();
                               }
                           });
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();
```

Obviously this code only works if i'm on my MainActivity since I create the builder like this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(mMainActivity.this);
```

Is there a way to create a builder based on the current activity even if it gets created on another one?

**EDIT:**

I tried with 
`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());`
But it doesn't work..

Comment: try using only `this` instead of `MainActivity.this`

Comment: what is the error @Signo

Comment: Do you want to show AlertDailog from service?

Comment: If you want to display Alert from service then you can use my code from below

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522700/show-an-alertdialog-from-another-activity-android/30523639#30523639

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to display Alert from your running service then you have to call new custom alert dialog class that will display alert whether you are on any activity.

```
    public class AlertDialogActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        displayAlert();
    }

    private void displayAlert()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
        builder.setMessage("You Message here").setCancelable(
            false).setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    // code here
                    AlertDialogActivity.this.finish();                  
                    dialog.cancel();                 
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Close",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    AlertDialogActivity.this.finish();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

And call this class from your service to display alert.

```
   Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlertDialogActivity.class);
getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `this` instead of `MainActivity.this`.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("title")
    .setMessage("A message?")
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // yes pressed
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // no pressed
        }
     })
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
     .show();
```

Comment: it gives me an error on new AlertDialog.Builder(this) but I have no suggestions on what the error could be

Comment: what is the name of the activity you are trying to alert a dialog

Comment: I mean if you write in a java file called `NewActivity.java`, then the this becomes `NewActivity.this`.

Comment: Yeah i know but I have only one activity that has the localization, if an event triggers I have to show the builder on the current active activity even if it is not the one where the localization service is

Comment: you could get the activity name from the `context` and then use it. `Activity activity = (Activity) context;`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an event bus or a custom skeleton class in order to connect these two. You can create this Bus and initialize in your Main Activity and keep a reference of it.

You'll create register and unregister method in your EventBus class.
Tie them to SharedPreference to hold reference.

When you call bus.register() it'll either create a new instance or return you the already created one.
bus.unregister will unregister the bus (do this when you logout or dont want to use bus anymore)

In your Activity A (The UI Activity)
Register your bus (in onResume) and subscribe to the event, lets call it EventShowDialog

```
@Subscribe
public void showEventDialog(EventShowDialog) event{
//show your dialog
}
```

In your main activity, where you'll initialize your bus, upon your even you just need to post the event

```
bus.post(new EventShowDialog)
```

EventShowDialog can be an empty class that you'll create. I've tried and tested this and it works as expected. Please reach out for more info if you get stuck somewhere.